# reduce, reduceByKey, reduceGroups in Spark or Flink

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, mapreduce, apache-flink

`reduce`: function takes accumulated value and next value to find some aggregation.

`reduceByKey`: is also the same operation with specified key.

`reduceGroups`: is apply specified operation to the grouped data.

I don't know how memory managed for these operations. For example, how data is taken while using `reduce` function(e.g all data loaded to the memory?)? I want to know how data is managed for reduce operations. I also want to know what is the difference between these operations according to the data management.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce is one of the cheapest operations in Spark,since that the only thing it does is actually grouping similar data to the same node.The only cost of a reduce operation is the reading of the tuple and a decision of where it should be grouped.
This means that the simple `reduce`,in contrast to the `reduceByKey` or `reduceGroups` is more expensive because Spark does not know how to make the grouping and searches for correlations among tuples.

Reduce can also ignore a tuple if it does not meet any requirement.